# How to use glyph from Apple Symbols font?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, fonts

I want to use one glyph from Apple Symbols font in my app. I open this font in CharactersPallete (from Snow Leopard), and this glyph's (lock symbol) id  (GID) is 5003, and it's not glyph's unicode number. How to place this symbol in my app, for example in TextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one way I can think of.. If you don't care if it's an image, open font book, make a large size and cut and paste a png :)

[This site](http://iosfonts.com/) shows the fonts available on iOS and I cannot find Apple Symbols there.

Comment: ow, my application not for iOS, it is Mac OS X application